# Redirecionamento com jQuery e PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, redirecionamento

Tenho duas páginas, onde uma que é a `.js` que faz a chamada via ajax a uma rotina em PHP para validar um usuário: https://pastebin.com/37RQtjUY

Outra página em PHP que é a chamada dessa rotina anterior onde eu vou validar o usuário pelo seu login e senha para remetê-lo ao restante do site: https://pastebin.com/SExFjj3V

Na linha 23 e 24 eu faço um `insert` numa tabela de *log*, porém, quando eu faço isso, eu tenho o retorno em JSON para a página que chamou essa rotina; na página `.js` esse retorno do PHP vem certinho, só que na linha 23 temos um redirecionamento para o `index_adm.php`, mas o jQuery não está fazendo isso.

Quando eu comento a linha 23 e 24 (ou seja, o `insert` na tabela de *log* em https://pastebin.com/SExFjj3V) funciona direitinho o redirecionamento. Somente quando eu insisto em fazer esse `insert` é que não funciona. Não estou entendendo o porquê disso.

Comment: Pode postar o arquivo que contém essa linha

Comment: no inspetor de elementos, vc consegue ver diferença nos responses com ou sem linha, de repente esteja retornando um true, um caracter especial ou até um erro, se conseguir inspecionar elemento, ir em network e efetuar a ação, verá a chamada um request e um response, tente analisar as diferenças....

Comment: Deixe o INSERT descomentado e no arquivo .js comente o redirecionamento, e coloque `console.log(response);` no `if` e veja o que aparece no console.

Comment: Vou ver e retorno

Comment: Não tinha pensado nisso, quando você fala em inspetor de elementos, você esta falando o que tem como extensão no chrome? Eu uso o fiddler para ver as requisições, retorno, do ajax, porém não utilizo todos os recursos, por falta de conhecimento

Comment: Ok utilizei isso e não apontou nenhum erro, não sei como postar uma imagem aqui, eu fiz uma do fiddler que eu utilizo

Comment: Poderia postar aqui o mostra o console?

Comment: Veja estou utilizando o fiddler, aqui esta o link da imagem https://snag.gy/91wZ8t.jpg, acho que ele aponta para um erro, mas sinceridade não estou conseguindo entender.
Utilizei o snag, pois não sei se tem como colocar uma imagem aqui, ou ainda não tenho permissão para isso, mas pelo snag da para saber um pouco

Answer (score 0):

Por quê vc não tenta com "prepare" e "execute" para ver se o php não está gerando um erro qdo vc faz o insert?

```
        $erros = array();

        $sql_in ="INSERT INTO log_user_on (fk_id_user_sistema,log_user_on_login_data) VALUES ( ?, ? ) ";

        // prepare 
        if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql_in)){

            //bind
            $stmt->bind_param("ss", $id_user, $hoje );

            //execute
            if ( $stmt->execute() ) {

                // echo "\n New records created successfully";

            }else{
                $erros["execute_error"] = $conn->error;
            }

            //close
            $stmt->close();

        }else{

            $erros["prepare_error"] = $conn->error;

        }

        $conn = null;

        $response = array("success" => true,"login"=>$varLogin,"id_user"=>$id_user,"token"=>$token, "erros"=>$erros);

        echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Não tinha pensado nisso, sou novato em php e ainda mais com pdo, vou  tentar obrigado

Comment: não deu resultado, não apontou nenhum erro

Comment: veja eu utilizei o fiddler e parece que ele esta apontando para algum erro,
https://snag.gy/91wZ8t.jpg

Comment: Se o login está retornando "1" e erros é "null", não tem nenhum problema no seu php. Se não está redirecionando com jquery `$(location).attr('href'...)`, tente com javascript puro: `location.href = 'index_adm.php?id='+id_user+'&token='+token`

Comment: Ok, vou tentar fazer isso, não pensei nisso, obrigado

Comment: Olha tentei isso e ainda continua o misterio de não fazer, realmente já estou pensando em procurar uma alternativa para isso